# Что означает команда bash?

Tags: bash

Не могу понять, что означает команда:

```
python script.py 1>${workspace_dir}/output1.txt 2>${workspace_dir}/output2.txt
```

После `python script.py` идут 2 аргумента или что это? А если так, то что они делают. Поясните.

Comment: перенаправление stdout и stderr https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/c11620.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это [описанное в стандарте posix перенаправление вывода](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02). его общий синтаксис:

```
команда [n]>файл
```

где `n` — это номер файлового дескриптора процесса, в котором выполняется `команда`.

если номер опущен, то подразумевается `1` (стандартный дескриптор вывода — `stdout`). эти две конструкции идентичны:

```
команда 1>файл
команда >файл
```

дескриптор номер `2` — это стандартный дескриптор вывода ошибок — `stderr`.

одна команда может сопровождаться несколькими перенаправлениями:

```
команда >файл1 2>файл2 3>файл3 ...
```

- в `файл1` будет записано то, что процесс выдал в `stdout` (дескриптор номер `1`)
- в `файл2` будет записано то, что процесс выдал в `stderr` (дескриптор номер `2`)
- в `файл3` будет записано то, что процесс выдал в дескриптор номер `3`
- и т.д.

---

существуют и другие синтаксические конструкции перенаправления вывода: `>|`, `>>`. чтобы не загромождать ответ, отсылаю к документации, ссылка на которую приведена в самом начале ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, идет перенаправление из 1 файлового дискриптора (стандартный вывод) в файл output1.txt, который находиться по пути, который определяет переменная окружения workspace_dir. Т.е. все, что выведет скрипт, пойдет в этот файл. Во втором аргументе почти тоже самое, но подменяется дискриптор стандартного вывода ошибок (stderr). Т.е., если в скрипте произойдет ошибка, то вывод о ней направиться в этот файл.